How to remove Google Drive and Gmail Bookmarks from Applications?
I have Google Chrome installed and it seems like installing Chrome leads to Google Drive and Gmail being listed as Applications in the Applications Overview screen, even though these packages are not installed. If I "open" these apps, it just opens Chrome on these Webistes, so they just seem to be web-app-like bookmarks added to the Apps list.
Does anyone know how I can remove these bookmarks?
I am running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
Thanks in advance
